# Trying to capture image for V380 IP Camera using java programming

Tags: camera, ip

I dont understand whats the problem here.I have done this code following a tutorial.Can anyone please help me with the code and process how can I capture image by the V380 ip camera?

[image]

Comment: which tutorial did u follow?

Comment: Posting a screenshot of your code doesn't help. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://youtu.be/3_GNE0t_VzY   this is the tutorial I followed